# Right-justify colorbox slightly to the left of bookcover's edge

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, bookcover

I'm looking to place a title in `colorbox`, in cls `bookcover`, that is right-justified, and leaving a margin to the left of the edge. I can somewhat get there using `tabularx` in cls `article`, but unable to replicate it in cls `bookcover`. Also, with `halign=right` uncommented, I get a blank (no title).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm]This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\end{tcolorbox}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox
{

  \tcbset{colback=lightgray,colframe=red!75!black}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.3\textwidth,arc=0mm]
    \begin{flushright}
      This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}\par slighty shifted to the left of the body of text border\par
    \end{flushright}
  \end{tcolorbox}

}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{  l   @{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
\usebox{\mybox} 
\end{tabularx}  
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image: article]

```
\documentclass[trimmed=true]{bookcover}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox
{

  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    width=0.4\textwidth
    ,arc=0mm
    ,colback=white
    ,colframe=red!75!black
    ,coltext=black
%    ,halign=right
    ]
%    \begin{flushright}
    Make this \textbf{tcolorbox}\par
    slighty shifted to the left \par
    of the bookcover's border\par
    and the text withing right justified
%    \end{flushright}

  \end{tcolorbox}

}    

\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}

  \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{blue}

  \bookcovercomponent{normal}{front}{ 

    \begin{center}
      \bfseries

      \vspace*{\fill}
      \begin{flushright}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{ l  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
          \usebox{\mybox} 
        \end{tabularx}  
      \end{flushright}

      \vspace*{\fill}

    \end{center}

  }


\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

[image: bookcover]

[image: halign=right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `enlarge right by={<somelength>}` key

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,width=5cm}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm,enlarge right by=2cm]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Application in `bookcover` class**

```
\documentclass[trimmed=true]{bookcover}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    
\tcbset{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,width=5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
  \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{blue}
  \bookcovercomponent{normal}{front}{ 
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm,enlarge right by=2cm]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
\vspace*{\fill}
}
\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks simpler, but it would be good to know why `tabularx` didn't work the same way in `bookcover` as it does for `article`. Also, the text has to be right justified within the box.

Comment: @Erwann I'm pretty sure that the problem does not specifically come from `tabularx`. However I am sure that adding boxing layers with `tabularx`, `tcolorbox` and others **is** a bad idea.